# Unicodе в std::string и конвертация в QString

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь назначить `std::string` юникод и вывести его в `QString`

```
std::string gpsCount(gps_satellite_count, '■');
ui->GPS_Anzeige->setText(QString::fromUtf8(gpsCount.c_str()));
```

Как вывод получаю `?????`. Как вывести в моем случае этот "квадратик"?

Comment: Там точно utf-8? Уместнее бы использовать `QString::fromStdString`.

Comment: А если вывести gpsCount - все нормально будет?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Если вывести просто gpsCount, то также выходит бред.. а вот с std::stringstream все нормально(правда он не подходит в этом случае).

Comment: @free_ze не помогло.

Comment: Попробуйте std::wstring использовать

Comment: А исходники кода в кодировке utf-8?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов получаю через debugg "ၥ\uDEA0ၥ\uDEA0ၥ\uDEA0ၥ\uDEA0ၥ\uDEA0ၥ\uDEA0" - что также отоброжается с вопросительным знаком

Comment: @Insider есть подозрение, что у вас отображение не умеет юникод.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов QLabel разве не умеет unicode?

Comment: @Insider должен уметь. А вот debugg и куда он там выводит - возможно и нет.

Comment: @Insider, должно быть `\u25A0`.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов     `std::wstring gpsCount(gps_satellite_count, '■');
    ui->GPS_Anzeige->setText(QString::fromStdWString(gpsCount.c_str()));` `GPS_Anzeige` - у меня `QLabel`

Comment: qDebug() << QString::fromStdWString(gpsCount.c_str()); вот так вытаюсь вывести через Debug.

Comment: @Insider А зачем c_str-то? Методы принимают std-строки

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов сначала пробовал с std::string поэтому оставил, но даже без c_str все равно выходит одно и тоже.

Comment: @free_ze если `qDebug() << "\u25A0";` то выдает квадратик.. а вот в `std::wstring gpsCount(gps_satellite_count, '\u25A0');
    ui->GPS_Anzeige->setText(QString::fromStdWString(gpsCount));` не хочет

Comment: если `wstring`, то `L"\u25A0"`. Но я почти уверен, что у вас исходник не в UTF-8, литерал, соответственно, тоже, отсюда все беды. Иначе хватило бы std::string.

Comment: @free_ze std::wstring gpsCount(gps_satellite_count, L'\u25A0'); так заработало.. на счет UTF-8, я до этого специально пересохранил файл в новой кодировке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string gpsCount(gps_satellite_count, '■');
```

Тут литерал `'■'` типом `int` передается в функцию которая принимает `char`.
И этот квадратик туда не пролазит.

Используйте `wstring`, или

```
std::string gpsCount;
for (auto i = gps_satellite_count; i-->0; )
  gpsCount += "■";
```